# What does DisplayNameFor do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm learning .NET Core with Razor pages, using one of the official tutorials [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), and I'm having trouble with this code:
`@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movie[0].Title)`

The tutorial says:

> The `DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor` HTML Helper inspects the `Title` property referenced in the lambda expression to determine the display name. The lambda expression is inspected rather than evaluated. That means there is no access violation when `model`, `model.Movie`, or `model.Movie[0]` is null or empty. When the lambda expression is evaluated, for example, with `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)`, the model's property values are evaluated.

Which I can't make heads or tails of. What does inspect mean here? Does it mean the lambda function runs in an try/catch, to prevent the access violation errors that the docs speak of? What does it mean exactly?

And in what important way is the second example (with `DisplayFor`) different? It uses `DisplayFor` instead of `DisplayName`, and another change is that it uses `ModelItem` instead of `model`. I don't know where it would get `ModelItem` from, `model` is made available by `@model (...)` at the op of the razor page but how `ModelItem` gets here is not clear to me.

The docs for `DisplayNameFor`are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper-1.displaynamefor?view=aspnetcore-5.0), but the tutorial links to the non-core docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynamefor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2), both of which are too terse for me to make much sense of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DisplayNameFor` will look for the [`Name` property of the `Display`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name?view=net-5.0#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_DisplayAttribute_Name) property attribute and print it to your razor page (or the property name itself, if it can't find it). So, if your model is

```
class Foo
{
    [Display(Name="My name")]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

It will display `My name` for `Prop1` and `Prop2` for `Prop2`.

The part about it being inspected rather than evaluated, means that it will look at your model definition, it will not try to get a value, so if the model value is `null`, it will not throw.

On the other hand, `DisplayFor` will print the value of the selected property, applying any format described by [DisplayFormatAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute?view=net-5.0), so the model is evaluated and cannot be null.

Typically you will use `DisplayNameFor` to build the table headers and `DisplayFor` to build the table data.

Comment: I think I get it now, and those docs are a lot more readable, thanks!

Comment: eh, both you and Nadia answered only half of the questions in my post, so it's both a difficult pick and I'm secretly hoping for a more comprehensive answer. Tomorrow after I've slept on it I'll pick the answer that helped me most.

Answer (score 1):

1. 

> What does inspect mean here?

DisplayNameFor is used to get the *name* of the property and not the value of it, so you will get *Title* and not *Pets 2*. In the second case the lambda expression would be evaluated - the first element of the movie list would be retrieved and then its title, that is not happening here.

The difference between evaluating and inspecting is similar to that between reading a book vs turning it around to find out who published it.

2)

> And in what important way is the second example (with DisplayFor) different?

DisplayFor is used to format the data itself (*Pets 2* and not the *Title*). In this case there is not much formatting involved because it is a string, but if it was a number for example you could specify how many digits you want to see ect.

3)

> I don't know where it would get ModelItem from

ModelItem  it is just the name of the variable to pass into the function. `modelItem => item.Title` is an equivalent of `MyFunction(Movie modelItem){return item.Title;}` modelItem can be called anything else, particularly as they don't even use it in the function itself and use `item` directly.

Comment: I think I get it a bit better now, still some questions. You quote my question 'what does inspect mean here' but in your answer I don't see much about 'inspect', can you clarify a bit? Also, how does modelItem get passed into the lambda?

Comment: Inspect here means that the lambda's semantic is being looked at. The framework needs to know which property is used, so it inspects metadata rather than evaluating the expression and getting data. With regards to modelItem - when you call DisplayFor, you pass it a function, so it can be re-written as DisplayFor(MyFunction), inside DisplayFor the function will be called, the model will come from the framework and passed to the function, which is in this case a lambda function.

Comment: "ModelItem it is just the name of the variable to pass into the function" yes, but where does it get the variable to pass into the function from? You say it's 'the model', is that the page model or the data model?

Comment: Page model, this one - @model RazorPagesMovie.Pages.Movies.IndexModel